# Using PPPoE with T-Online in Germany

Tags: adsl, adsl-router

I've been trying to get my DrayTek ADSL router to connect using PPPoE to t-online here in Germany I called customer support and thought I'd gotten the information I needed. Unfortunately it still doesn't appear to work. Are there any t-online (Germany) customers that have configured their own routers and can give me some pointers.

To connect I need to enter a username and password I was told that the username should be in the format:
Anschlusskennung (12 digit number)
T-Online Nummer(12 digit number)
Mitbenutzernummer (4 digit number)
@t-online.de
e.g
0000000000001111111111112222@t-online.de

I have tried to connect with the username in this format but I get no connection I did notice that my email address (which I obviously don't use is) in the format:
111111111111-2222@t-online.de
Which makes me think that I'm just missing some key formatting information. I'd appreciate any help here as I have a very good router sitting here gathering dust.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need three numbers: "Anschlusskennung" (always 12 digits), "Teilnehmernummer" (12 or less digits) and "Mitbenutzerkennung" (4 digits) and your password.

**Example Data**:

- Anschlusskennung: 111111111111
- Teilnehmernummer: 222222222222 (12 digits) or 33333333333 (11 digits)
- Mitbenutzerkennung: 0001

**Example 1** (Teilnehmernummer with 12 digits):

```
1111111111112222222222220001@t-online.de
```

**Example 2** (Teilnehmernummer with 11 digits):

```
11111111111133333333333#0001@t-online.de
```

Some routers have problems with the "#" sign so you can try this:

**Example 2a** (Teilnehmernummer with 11 digits):

```
11111111111133333333333\#0001@t-online.de
```

If you are using "T-DSL Business" you'll only need the "Benutzerkennung" (12 digits, here `444444444444`) and the format looks like this:

**Example 3** (T-DSL Business):

```
t-online-com/444444444444@t-online-com.de
```

Comment: As I mention in my post my Teilnehmernummer is 12 digits and I entered the username in the same format as you have in Example 1 which makes me think that I must have the correct user name and password. 

I guess my problem is going to be discovering where the problem is if its not the username.

Answer (score 1):

i found [this](http://bugs.gentoo.org/89061), maybe you'll need the `#` sign:

> Enter your PPPoE user name (default
>   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX#0001@t-online.de)

and [here](http://www.raycomp.com/AMIGA-DSL-FAQ.htm):

"Anschlusskennung is a 12-digit number. "T-Online-Nr" is a number consisting of up to 12 digits. "Mitben.-Kennung" is usually "0001".

For example for an "Anschlusskennung" of "000123456789", a "T-Online-Nr" of "321111111111" and the primary user (Mitben.-Kennung "0001") the login name would be: `000123456789321111111111#0001@t-online.de`

Comment: I really thought you had the answer there, but I just tried it and it didn't work. Thanks for trying